# K8s operator listen to specific config map

Tags: go, kubernetes

I've an operator which run a reconcile for some object changes, now I want to add ability to reconcile when specific `configmap` is changing, (my operator **doesn't** responsible on this CM just needs to listen to it and read on changes...) from the docs I think I need to use the `Owns(&corev1.Configmap{})` but not sure how to do it and provide specific configmap name to watch,

How should I refer to specific configmap `name: foo` in `namespace=bar`

https://sdk.operatorframework.io/docs/building-operators/golang/references/event-filtering/#using-predicates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't used this specific operator framework, but the concepts are familiar. Create a predicate function like this and use it when you are creating a controller by passing it into the SDK's `WithEventFilter` function:

```
func specificConfigMap(name, namespace string) predicate.Predicate {
    return predicate.Funcs{
        UpdateFunc: func(e event.UpdateEvent) bool {
            configmap := e.NewObject.(*corev1.ConfigMap)
            if configmap.Name == name && configmap.Namespace == namespace {
                return true
            }
            return false
        },
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks will give it a try and let you know :)

Comment: It works thanks! while debug it it seems that it stops in `return false` for all the config map in the cluster, is there any efficient way which I can filter it to reduce the load ?

Comment: Your controllers require an initial sync of all objects after which only the updates to those objects are received. Kubernetes controllers use "informers" to cache objects locally when the controller first starts up. This allows informers to only require notification about the changes after the initial state is synced.

Comment: could you please provide some example?

Comment: What I'm saying is that the answer to your question, "is there any efficient way which I can filter it to reduce the load" is no for the reasons I provided. Internally the controller requires processing each `ConfigMap` (in your case) that exists. So no, there's not way to reduce the load by not performing an initial sync of the objects the controller is responsible for, this is how controllers work. You can learn more about this [here](https://engineering.bitnami.com/articles/a-deep-dive-into-kubernetes-controllers.html)